# POST update to Twitter using Oauth and HTTR, R

Tags: r, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, httr

I am trying to post an update to Twitter using the api.  Following the steps at https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/demo/oauth1-twitter.r, I can get the GET call to work, but I haven't managed to get the POST to work.  Here is the relevant code:

```
library(httr)
library(httpuv)


oauth_endpoints("twitter")

myapp <- oauth_app("twitter", 
key = "key"
secret = "secret" 
) 

twitter_token <- oauth1.0_token(oauth_endpoints("twitter"), myapp)


#this works fine
req <- GET("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json", 
config(token = twitter_token)) 



#this doesn't work.  Returns error 403: status is forbidden
POST(url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json",
     body = "test", 
     config(token = twitter_token)
     )
```

Any solution that allows a status update (Tweet) from R is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update) say you need to pass a parameter `status` as a query parameter, not in the body, which makes sense b/c it can only be 140 characters long anyway.

```
POST("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json",
     query = list(status = "testing from R"),
     config(token = twitter_token)
)
```

Comment: Done.  Thanks for your help.